# HTML table loses border when mail is forwarded

Tags: java, html, css

I am trying to include HTML tables with Outlook emails. It is able to render and provide the content when the mail is sent initially. But, the table loses it's border whenever the mail is forwarded. But, the structure is preserved.

Is there anyway to embed some css so that the content is rendered whenever the mail is forwarded ?

EDIT : I am using outlook to send the mails and the tables are already inline styled. Also the code is written for generation of email using apache velocity engine.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Have you tried inlining all style in the html: `<div style="color:red"></div>`

Comment: E-mail is always a pain when you try fancy lay-outs. And when it works in Outlook, you might see it doesn't work in Gmail. Inline styling, as suggested by Artog, is a valid approach (`<table style="border: 1px solid black;">`).

Comment: Im using outlook to send the mails. The code is written using apache velocity engine and inline styling has also been applied

Answer (score 1):

it's wired as each email client treats forwarded messages, so if gmail adds some classes to restyle the forwarded tables I don't think there's much you can do about that. I would suggest trying to use some divs inside table cells and give a border to those.

and there's a tool that will help you so much when writing email templates, called emogrefier. basically you write css and it automatically applies that style as inline. you can even use scss and set the exported file to be included as inline style.

Comment: Im using outlook to send the mails. The code is written using apache velocity engine and inline styling has also been applied